# How to add variable to ionic iframe?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

How to add variable to ionic iframe?

```html
<ion-content>
    <iframe src="http://local/server_api/pr.php?p={{variable}}"
            style="width: 100%; min-height: 100%; height: 100%;" 
            frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
```

It's not working. Blank page.

Answer (score 0):

try:

check once : `[src]="maps.google.com/maps?q={{details.latitude}},{{details.longitude}}&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed">`